# Whole week camping on O'ahu (Hawaii) possible?

Tags: usa, camping, hawaii

I am planning to go on a two week camping trip to O'ahu. However, it seems that all camping areas are 3-day or 5-day only, i.e, you cannot stay there for two full weeks. Camping always starts at friday and extends until monday / wednesday. Is there any exception? Are there parks where I can camp for two full weeks?

And in addition: What is the idea behind all this? I have never experienced such a thing anywhere in the world. Why am I not allowed to arrive and depart when I want?

Comment: I remember having read in a guidebook that the maximum stay is held fairly short to deter homeless people installing themselves in campgrounds. Can't find a reference right now though...

Answer (score 3):

Lots of campgrounds, especially government run campgrounds and doubly especially low or no cost campgrounds, have limits on how many days you can stay there ...including all state campgrounds in Hawaii.

The purpose is to control squatters, not specifically homeless, but folks who prefer to not pay rent or rv parking fees and take advantage of free camping.

You won't be able to spend your entire trip at one campground, but will have to move around and perhaps occasionally spring for a motel room.

And hopefully you realize that Hawaii state campgrounds tend to draw locals for nighttime beer drinking sessions, have very basic restrooms, and showers are primarily outdoor showers (cold water) for rinsing salt water off after swimming, not for stripping down and washing up with soap and shampoo.